# Salesforce "View All" Permissions on a Detail Object, Will it give view all on the Master Object because of Master-Detail Relationship?

Tags: security, permissions, salesforce, master-detail, force.com

I've researched/read what I can on Master-Detail relationships in Salesforce but still have a query regarding permissions:

If I grant "**View All**" access to the **Detail Object** in a Master-Detail relationship (so that everyone with the permissions set can view all records of this custom object type) does this mean that the users will have "View All" access to the records in the **Master Object**?

Research I've done:

- http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/relationships_considerations.htm
- http://isv.platformatyourservice.com/wiki/Master-Detail_relationship
- https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/dev_security.htm

I've typed *several variations* of this question into Google without any luck, so if someone with SF expertise can help it would be *much appreciated*! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

And, no need to trust me, because it is very easy to test.

Comment: thanks for replying! any chance you could share a link that explains *how* to **test** this...? thanks.

Comment: To test you could create two objects, create a master-detail relationship between them, and then add some test records.  Next you would create a profile with the View All on the detail object, and a view all on the master object.  Make sure the org-wide default is private for the master.  Then create two test users, one for each profile.  Optionally, you could have one test user but you would need to change their profile inbetween testing.  Then you try to view the master records as each test user, and see what you see.